# Increase 2 min timeout on ASP.NET Core 2.0 web app hosted in Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I get the following error message with this code after exactly 2 minutes: "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process".

```
public async Task<bool> AddRange<TEntity>(IList<TEntity> items) where TEntity : class
{
    _db.AddRange(items);
    return await _db.SaveChangesAsync() >= 0;;
}
```

I'm using Entity Framework Core to save data to Azure SQL Database.
How can I increase the time the application waits before throwing this message?
Thank you all!

Comment: No web app should have a 2-minute response time... but you're going to have to identify the _specific_ type of Azure service used to host the app.